# Sort Array by highest value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sort my array order by highest value of score.

it's a json data

```
"score":[
    {
        "userId":"5",
        "playtime":"1396369254",
        "score":"25"
    },
    {
        "userId":"1",
        "playtime":"1396369056",
        "score":"12"
    },
    {
        "userId":"2",
        "playtime":"1396369240",
        "score":"100"
    }
],
```

here score 100 will be first index

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [the PHP documentation for sorting arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)?

Answer (score 3):

use php's function `usort` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['score'] == $b['score']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['score'] < $b['score']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($DATA, "cmp");
```